# Using DenseVector as input labels for PySpark random forest modelling

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, random-forest, apache-spark-ml

I have a processed dataframe that takes the form:

```python
+--------+----------+
| labels | features |
+--------+----------+
|[1,0,0] |    1     |
+--------+----------+
|[0,0,0] |    0     |
+--------+----------+
....
```

In which the `labels` are of the type `DenseVector` and `features` are integers.

I am trying to use the PySpark ML libraries to train a random forest model with this data, but I keep encountering the following error:

`pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column features must be of type NumericType but was actually of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7.'`

When running the following bit of code:

```python
def generateModel(dataSet):

# Begin generating our model object.
modelType = RandomForestClassifier()

# Model parameters stored here.
modelParameters = ParamGridBuilder() \
         .baseOn({modelType.labelCol: 'features'}) \
         .baseOn([modelType.predictionCol, 'label']) \
         .addGrid(modelType.numTrees, [5]) \
         .addGrid(modelType.maxDepth, [7]) \
         .build()

evaluatorObject = CrossValidator(estimator=modelType,
                    estimatorParamMaps=modelParameters,
                    evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                    numFolds=4)

trainedModel = evaluatorObject.fit(dataSet)

return trainedModel
```

I am using the `ml` libraries and not the `mllib` as I know there are some issues when using the `DenseVector` method.

Comment: So, your label column is named `features`, and your features column is named `labels`? Quite confusing, don't you think?